# How draw phylogenetic tree using Python

Tags: python, numpy, bioinformatics, biopython

I have a distance matrix of some species in an Excel file and want to draw a phylogenetic tree in Python. Is it possible, If yes, then which command should be given? The distance matrix is given in  excel file.

### Data Table

|  | Arbo | Barb | Hirs | Aust | Darw | Tomen | Stur | Tril |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Arbo | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Barb | 0.14 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Hirs | 1.15 | 1.16 | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |
| Aust | 0.14 | 0 | 1.16 | 0 |  |  |  |  |
| Darw | 1.78 | 1.77 | 1.81 | 1.77 | 0 |  |  |  |
| Tomen | 2.03 | 2.02 | 2.02 | 2.02 | 0.51 | 0 |  |  |
| Stur | 1.81 | 1.82 | 1.83 | 1.82 | 0.76 | 0.97 | 0 |  |
| Tril | 1.91 | 1.92 | 1.95 | 1.92 | 0.78 | 0.74 | 0.71 | 0 |

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'Book1.csv')
UPGMATree = constructor.upgma(df)
NJTree = constructor.nj(df)
```

I try these commands but not construct tree. I was expecting like this
[image]

Comment: Did you print `UPGMATree` or `NJTree`?  That module constructs a tree data structure, but it doesn't DRAW the tree.

Comment: Both UPGMATree and NJTree

Comment: A quick scan of the documentation shows that, once you HAVE a tree, you can use `Phylo.draw(tree)` to draw the tree.

Comment: I have table of data and want to draw tree from this table as shown in figure.  By using these commands I can draw tree from DNA sequences, But I want this table to draw tree.

Comment: Yes.  That's what `Phylo.draw` is supposed to do.  Have you read the documentation?  https://biopython.org/wiki/Phylo

Comment: Have you read https://gist.github.com/fransua/da703c3d2ba121903c0de5e976838b71 ?

Comment: In your data set Raim and Exig is not there, when I see tree, but I have provided your answer , see

Answer (score 0):

I think u have already matrix which may generate dy NJ, or ML, or MP, etc, so u can go directly as below, keep in mind sometime, u have to change diagonal with 100, or 1 so u will get better tree, Here I have kept as 0 as u mentioned in your query, so tree is quite different, so try change to 1 and your expected tree u will get
import pandas as pd
from scipy.cluster import hierarchy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

```
# Sample data
data = {
    'Arbo': [0, 0.14, 1.15, 0.14, 1.78, 2.03, 1.81, 1.91],
    'Barb': [0, 0, 1.16, 0, 1.77, 2.02, 1.82, 1.92],
    'Hirs': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1.81, 2.02, 1.83, 1.95],
    'Aust': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'Darw': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.51, 0.76, 0.78],
    'Tomen': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.97, 0.74],
    'Stur': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.71],
    'Tril': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
}

# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=data.keys())

# Create a lower triangular matrix
lower_triangle = np.tril(df)

# Create a hierarchical clustering using UPGMA method
linkage_matrix = hierarchy.average(lower_triangle)

# Plot the dendrogram
dendrogram = hierarchy.dendrogram(linkage_matrix, labels=df.index, orientation='right')
```

[image]

but as u change diagonal to 1

```
as below 
# Sample data
data = {
    'Arbo': [1, 0.14, 1.15, 0.14, 1.78, 2.03, 1.81, 1.91],
    'Barb': [0, 1, 1.16, 0, 1.77, 2.02, 1.82, 1.92],
    'Hirs': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1.81, 2.02, 1.83, 1.95],
    'Aust': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'Darw': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.51, 0.76, 0.78],
    'Tomen': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.97, 0.74],
    'Stur': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.71],
    'Tril': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
}

# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=data.keys())

# Create a lower triangular matrix
lower_triangle = np.tril(df)

# Create a hierarchical clustering using UPGMA method
linkage_matrix = hierarchy.average(lower_triangle)

# Plot the dendrogram
dendrogram = hierarchy.dendrogram(linkage_matrix, labels=df.index, orientation='right')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=data.keys())
print(df)

Arbo  Barb  Hirs  Aust  Darw  Tomen  Stur  Tril
Arbo   1.00  0.00  0.00     0  0.00   0.00  0.00     0
Barb   0.14  1.00  0.00     0  0.00   0.00  0.00     0
Hirs   1.15  1.16  1.00     0  0.00   0.00  0.00     0
Aust   0.14  0.00  0.00     1  0.00   0.00  0.00     0
Darw   1.78  1.77  1.81     0  1.00   0.00  0.00     0
Tomen  2.03  2.02  2.02     0  0.51   1.00  0.00     0
Stur   1.81  1.82  1.83     0  0.76   0.97  1.00     0
Tril   1.91  1.92  1.95     0  0.78   0.74  0.71     1
```

[image]